# Dúvia teórica sobre captcha e curl php

Tags: php, libcurl, captcha

Eu vi trechos de códigos em que as pessoas usam o `curl` para pegar a imagem do captcha, mas é possível pegar a `string` que está na imagem ?

Pelo que entendi, a complexidade de pegar o captcha depende do código que cada site usa para gerá-lo, é isso mesmo ?

Por exemplo, qual seria o script responsável por gerar o catpcha [deste link aqui](http://emec.mec.gov.br/emec/nova-index/#simples) ?

Então não é possível criar um código universal para pegar o captcha dos site ?

Comment: O CURL você pega qualquer coisa que está na página, simples assim, incluindo a imagem. Depois, usa OCR para tentar pegar as palavras/letras que estão na imagem ou você pode utilizar reconhecimento por voz e utilizar o captcha em modo de áudio. A diferença é que cada Captcha é um captcha, não há como ter algo universal. Uns são operações matemáticas, outros são trechos de livros, outros são imagens que contêm alguma X coisa, outros são palavras aleatórias, outras são publicidades.... Se existe vários tipos de captcha, como haveria "um código universal"?! O principio tende a ser o mesmo.

Comment: Hmmm entendi, faz sentido.Você conhece alguma biblioteca de ocr free ? ou alguma api ocr que eu possa utilizar pra isso ?